# Change value in Dynamic array based on string input

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am trying to create a dynamic array using JSON.net, My idea is pretty simple but I have encountered an issue I don't know how to get around.

```
static dynamic SaveValue <T> (dynamic JsonArray, string Object, T Value) {
 JsonArray.Object = Value;
 return JsonArray;
}
```

Now the object is where the string should be used to get the element, It will contain the value to be serialized later

```
Json = SaveValue<bool>(Json, "Bhop.Enabled", true);
```

The usage is like this

---

I have tried:
Googling this and looking for functions but I'm stuck, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? Its not clear what you are trying to achieve? Provide more details with proper sample.

Comment: I did provide enough info, I am trying to make it so the string will be used to change the value in the object, In the example i do Bhop.Enabled now i want that to be used so it will do JsonArray.Bhop.Enabled = Value;

Comment: The sample you shared will not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not getting fully what you are trying to achieve but the following code will help to dynamically generate the json object based on string key and the value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic Json = new JObject() as dynamic;
    Json = SaveValue<bool>(Json, "Bhop.Enabled", true);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static dynamic SaveValue<T>(dynamic jsonArray, string Object, T Value)
{
    jsonArray = new JObject();
    jsonArray.Add(Object,Value);
    return jsonArray;
}
```

Comment: o i see where i failed to explain, So pretty much that doesn't do as i wanted or work because i want the dot to be a pretty much like this {
 "Bhop": {
  "Enabled":true,
  "MaxHops":"5",
 },
 "Other": {
  "Enabled":true
 }
} Also this does not stack

Comment: Actually forget i said anything it doesnt matter, No one is going to look at configs anyway there will be a GUI, So yes this works 80%